# how to fix this error with proxy in uc driver python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

i use this code with undetected driver options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=http://host:port')
but when driver open this page i get this error :
didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

how can i fix this please help me ?

options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=http://host:port')